# Gradle Grails - How can I disable H2 database console only on production environment?

Tags: grails

I want to use H2 database console of a Grails application in development environment but I do not want to use it on production environment for security reasons.

How can I disable it only on production environment ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The console is disabled by default in production. You have to enable it if you want to use it.

As you can see [in the docs](https://grails.github.io/grails-doc/2.4.x/guide/conf.html#databaseConsole) there are two configurable settings. So if you wanted to *enable* the console in production and change its uri to be under /admin you would do this:

```
environments {
   production {
      grails.dbconsole.enabled = true
      grails.dbconsole.urlRoot = '/admin/dbconsole'
   }
}
```

See [the source code](https://github.com/grails/grails-core/blob/2.4.x/grails-plugin-datasource/src/main/groovy/org/codehaus/groovy/grails/plugins/datasource/DataSourceGrailsPlugin.groovy#L248) for more details.

Answer (score 0):

As of Grails 3 the better way is to change settings in `application.yml` file using YAML syntax. So this would be:

```
environments:
    production:
        dbconsole:
            enabled: true
            urlRoot: '/admin/dbconsole'
```